# Javascript: How can I replace the contents of a string but not in an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, replace, indexing

I want to write a Javascript function to change the text **Lasvegas** in string: 
example:

> "**Hello every one in Lasvegas, come to <a href='xxx'>Lasvegas</a> with me**"

How can I change the text "Lasvegas" but not change the content **Lasvegas** that is in an HTML tag?

Comment: what do you mean by start tag and end tag, do you mean a HTML string? -- never mind I edited your question and see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like that

```
str.replace(/Lasvegas[^<]/,'123')
```

Comment: This would only work if `Lasvegas` didn't come at the end of the string and your regex may need to be global  (`g` modifier) if more than one occurrence needs replacing.

Comment: it check ok! but when it contant "Lastvegas" with some character other in start and end tag it error !
ex: <a>Lastvegas abc ef</a> it wrong

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Forgot JavaScript supports negative lookaheads:

```
"Hello every one in Lasvegas, come <a href='xxx'>Lasvegas</a> with me"
    .replace(/(Lasvegas(?!<))/g, "World");
```

Returns:

> Hello every one in World, come <a href='xxx'>Lasvegas</a> with me

---

Left in so everyone can see how pointless my first answer was ;-)

Alexey's answer would work if "Lasvegas" wasn't at the end of the string.  I'm not sure if there's a better way, but you could use a replacer function to assert whether the text is inside a tag or not:

```
var str = "Hello every one in Lasvegas, come <a href='xxx'>Lasvegas</a> with me";
var out = str.replace(
            /(>?Lasvegas<?)/g,
            function ($0) 
            { 
                if ($0.slice(0,1) == ">") 
                    return $0; 
                else
                    return "World";
            }
);
```

contents of `out`:

> Hello every one in World, come <a href='xxx'>Lasvegas</a> with me

Comment: i still have some problems with it, when i put the same character in attribute of tag. Ex: <a href='Lasvegas abc'>Lasvegas Text</a>. it false. Please help !

Thanks

Comment: @TuanTDA: The `(?!<)` part of my regular expression is a negative lookahead.  It will match the content that precedes that lookahead only if the content in the lookahead does not follow the matched text.  If you change the lookahead to `(?!(?:[^<]*<)|(?:[^'>]*'>))`, it should do a better job.

Comment: Sorry ! for spent your time ! if you don't mind please help last question. when i apply (?!(?:[^<]*<)|(?:[^'>]*'>) i still meet error ! all text in attribute not replace but it only replace the last text of string. you can check below for detail.

I do as below:

var str = "<br/>Visit <a href='Microsoft' class='Microsoft abc'>Microsoft abc</a> check Microsoft and replace with Tuan string <a href='tuantda@fpt.net'> Microsoft abc</a> welcome to Microsoft";
var out = str.replace(/(Microsoft(?!(?:[^<]*<)|(?:[^'>]*'>)))/g, " Tuan ")        
document.write(out);        

thanks

Comment: Although JavaScript has lookahead, there are bugs in IE that make it go wrong in weird ways. Hence it is best avoided.

Comment: @bobince: I'll try and remember that.  I did test the regex I added to the answer and it worked just fine with the input in the question, although it's hardly a complicated regex by any standard.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't worked out what the exact circumstances are that cause JScript's regexp lookahead to freak out, so I tend to avoid it altogether. Some background: http://regexadvice.com/blogs/mash/archive/2009/02/21/Looking-again-at-the-Lookahead-bug.aspx